# Show that intersection is open

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let be $X$ a normed space, $Q\subseteq X$ an open subset (of $X$) and $M\subseteq X$. In general it is not possible to say if $Q\cap M$ is open or not. However, if we look at $Q\cap M$ with regard to $M$ we can prove it.

**My apporach:**

Let be $x\in Q\cap M$. As $Q$ is open (with regard to $X$) there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $U_{\epsilon}(x):=\{y\in X\mid |x-y|<\epsilon\}\subseteq Q$. For this particular $\epsilon$ it also follows $U_{\epsilon}(x)\cap M=\{y\in M\mid |x-y|<\epsilon\}\subseteq M$. Hence, $Q\cap M$ is open.

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you attempting to prove that $Q\cap M$ is open in the set $M$? If so, this is automatically true by the definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: Yes, but I have not yet attended a topology course, so I tired it this way.

Comment: In that case, then this is in some sense correct, so long as you have a definition of what it means to be open in subsets of vector spaces.